# Composer autoload definition for class with mismatching filename

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to convert a legacy library class to using Composer.

However, currently the filename and class name are out of sync. While these need to be brought in sync as part of broader refactoring, that has knock-on effects and my objective at present is to migrate dependencies to Composer so that deployment can be modernised.

Currently the package is called `myfoo`, with the file at `src/myFoo.php` (which is consistent), but the class inside is inconsistently called `foo`. There are many external applications which call `new foo`, so the class name cannot at this point be easily changed, though that will happen in future (it needs namespacing etc., anyway, so that is the point to make that change).

Currently my autoload in composer.json is:

```
     "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/myFoo.php"]
     }
```

which I believe matches the documentation at https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files.

However, client code calls fail on `new foo` with `Class "foo" not found`.

What should the `autoload` definition be in this circumstance?

Comment: I hate to ask, but your clients are loading the vendor/autoload.php, right?

Comment: @Chris Haas Yes. Other dependencies are confirmed loading.

Comment: I'm not certain why that wouldn't work, but I would note that if `myFoo.php` only has the class declaration, you can use the `classmap` directive, `"classmap": ["src/myFoo.php"]`

Comment: @Chris Haas Thanks - yes, that workaround of using the `classmap` method instead has worked. If you want to promote this as an answer, I'll accept it (unless there are more direct solutions to the question, but this is a much appreciated workaround!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain why the `files` directive wouldn't work in this case, however, if `myFoo.php` only declares the `Foo` class, you can use the `classmap` directive instead:

```
     "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src/myFoo.php"]
     }
```